# How prevent Azure stream analytics job to read incomplete file

Tags: azure, stream, azure-stream-analytics

I created stream analytics job in Azure which read data from file(s) in blob storage (from defined container in blob storage) and this job put data from file(s) into Cosmos DB SQL API. How I can prevent Azure strean analytics job to read incomplete file(s). I do not want that be possible that job get incomplete (still writting file).

Answer (score 0):

As i know,ASA job can't identify which files are incomplete files, which are completed files.Once you set defined input...start job,it will collect any stream data from input side in the real-time.That's the feature of ASA!

Back to your requirement:you want to transfer data and you are pushing data at the same time.But you wanna let the transmission is executed by some specific status of files.

I'm afraid that ASA is not your option. Trigger with ETL service maybe more appropriate for you.You could get an idea of [Azure Data Factory copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) which supports trigger execution. Once you finish your pushing data,you could trigger the ADF to transfer data from blob storage into cosmos db.

Comment: In my case for exampe I have 5 files in blob storage. Is possible maybe to know when ASA job is finished with transfer of data from this 5 files into CosmosDB, and then somehow automatically stop the job? And if this is possible, is there possibility to start again job from Azure function?